# Errors when install Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to install magento 2 from tar archive (without using cli).
Can’t install on new ubuntu 16.04 server.
it shows these errors 
[image: magento2errors]

The magento check configurations file shows that everything is Ok
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing Magento1 with Magento 2.

Here it is the system requirements for M2

[Magento 2 system requirements](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html)

Then the error log it's pretty self explained: open_basedir is in effect.

A quick google search and you would already know what is all about (eg [here](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.templatemonster.com/help/open_basedir-restriction-in-effect-filex-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths-y.html&ved=0ahUKEwjkt7279NDOAhWLWywKHXtdC-EQFggiMAE&usg=AFQjCNHE8DHo8AfhGerKBmGisYOtU5e21w) and  [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/Setup-error-quot-Warning-realpath-open-basedir-restriction-in/td-p/27922) )

Start from fixing sys requirements..

Answer (score 0):

x86fantini - thank you!

I've solved this problem.
If you have the same problem, you should edit your vhost file for you domain at /etc/apache2/vhosts/www-root/high-kpi.com

at line from `php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/user/data:.`

to `php_admin_value open_basedir "none"`